# Instant run shortcut does not work in Android Studio 3.3

Tags: android-studio

I was using Android Studio for Flutter, but when I switched back for android development the instant run button no longer responds to shortcut key(it works fine for button clicks).

I installed the older version 3.1 which worked well but after updating to 3.3 I am facing the same problem.

Android Studio 3.3
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5199772, built on December 25, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.13.0-46-generic

Can I change the shortcut key to anything else?

Comment: Check your Keymap in Settings and see if your shortcut key was reassigned to something else, and perhaps assign it back.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't see any option to update the keymap which says "Apply Changes" on the hint. There is an option "Update running application" but doesn't do anything. Also, it still works well in version 3.1 with the shortcut key.

Comment: I can confirm I have the same issue.

Comment: @Phat7 I have found the issue to be version related. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54420094/instant-run-missing-in-android-studio-3-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been fixed in versions >= `3.3.2`. The setting is now called `Apply Changes` and will work with keymap changes.

Also, see [Instant Run missing in Android Studio 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54420094/instant-run-missing-in-android-studio-3-3/55000153#55000153)

Answer (score 1):

File
Settings
Keymap
Menu
Run
(double click to) Apply Changes or other item
Add Keyboard Shortcut 
put new your key shortcut 
OK (or Apply).

Comment: consider explaining why this works and how it solves the original problem