# Instant Run missing in Android Studio 3.3

Tags: android-studio, android-instant-run, hot-reload

Currently, in the Android Studio version 3.3, the shortcut for "Apply Changes" option is missing which allows Instant Run. There is another option called "Update Running Application" which does not provide the same functionality.

This option was available in older versions like 3.1 as seen in the screenshot

[image: comparision]

I am unable to use Instant Run feature in version 3.3.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been fixed in Android Studio 3.3.2, but you have to (re)define the shortcut yourself (at least for the default Mac OS X Keymap).

Comment: my apologies for late accepting the answer, couldn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `CTRL+F10`. The keymap doesn't work in android studio 3.3

Answer (score -1):

**Update Running Application** is same as **Apply Changes**

You can use same shortcuts <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>

Thank you.

Comment: I tried but it does not update the changes in the current activity. However, if I click on the toolbar icon which says "Apply changes" then Instant Run works. But not with the shortcut in version 3.3.  In version 3.1 shortcut as well as the icon works.

Comment: I can confirm I have the same issue. Instant Run has changed to Apply Changes in the shortcuts key mapping as well, but none of the shortcuts work for that command.

Comment: @Phat7 is there a workaround? It's a mess having to click the button every time to use the instant run feature.