# Flutter hot reload not working on tablet emulator

Tags: flutter, tablet, hot-reload

I am developing an app in `Flutter` with Android Studio 3.3.1.

I have just started the project, deleted a few boilerplate code about the default counter app and also created a tablet emulator.

I can run the code in the tablet without any problem pressing the play button, but when I make some changes in the code i do not get the hot reload button activated.

I have tried running the same app on another mobile emulator and the hot reload button actually works.

Anyone got the same problem?

**The issue is happening with the emulator: Nexus 10 API Q**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is related to Android Studio 3.3.1 version.
I had a similar problem.

See [Instant run shortcut does not work in Android Studio 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54404417/instant-run-shortcut-does-not-work-in-android-studio-3-3)

and [Instant Run missing in Android Studio 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54420094/instant-run-missing-in-android-studio-3-3)

Update to the latest version which is 3.4 or downgrade to version 3.2

Comment: updating to 3.4 did not solve the issue, hot reload still not working on tablet

Comment: did you fix the keymapping?

Comment: do i need? even the hot reload icon on the top corner is not activated when i change code...

Comment: are other emulators working? if yes, then try to run other android version on tablet. If other versions work then version Q is the problem. Try running Q on other emulators to verify.

Comment: yeah probably the best solution, other emulators (not Q) work in mobile devices, i need to test tablet with non-Q version.....we will see..Thanks!!

Comment: btw, Q is preview so there may some issues and the latest version of the emulator is 29.0.9. do update it.

Comment: what exactly was the problem? was it the emulator or the version Q?

Comment: was Q, changed to Pie (API 28) and all work as normal, both on tablet and mobile emulators. Thanks again.